# 400 error while making http request in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, http-error, get-request

I ctrl+c the part of Max Payne Wiki article(it's just an exmaple of any text):

[just a screenshot of how I copy part of the article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YbV5.png)

Then I ctrl+v this stuff into `<textarea>` in my site(not in the code, but literally in the site-rendered `<textarea>`)

The the runs the next javascript code:

```
SomeParagraphElement.innerText=document.getElementById('my_txtarea').value;
requestp("aga.php?data="+SomeParagraphElement.innerText, callback_function);
```

where `requestp` is

```
function requestp(path, run)
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', path, true); 

request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200))
run( request.responseText);
}
);

request.send(null);

}
```

After this there should be a data uploaded to sever, but it doesn't happen and if I just write stuff from keyboard by my fingers and even insert emojis - all works fine.

Google Chrome debug window says, that I make a 400 HTTP error. I tried

`var str= SomeParagraphElement.innerHTML.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '%0A');` and another %blahblah symbol, but it doesn't change anything.

If I make a new line by myself by pressing 'enter', via keyboard it works fine.

What should I do?

Comment: Seems the problem is in GET request length(2048b max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, if I pass data more the 2048 bytes, I have to use POST request. Here is a function, maybe it will be helpfull for someone

```
function requestp(path, data, callback)
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', path, true); 
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');//specify this!

request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200))
callback( request.responseText);
}
);

request.send(data);

}
```